# Unable to send sms when mms is in sending state. Is this a android M design?

Tags: android, shell, android-layout, android-studio

I have updated my phone to android M.
After this update if i try to send mms and the sms then, it do not send sms until mms is in sending state. Before this update i can send sms irrespective of mms state but now i can't.
Is this a Android M design ?

Thanks

Comment: Uh, no. How are you sending them, exactly?

Comment: If MMS is in sending state, then we can't send SMS.
To send SMS wait for the MMS to send or cancel the MMS then we can send SMS.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: I do not have the code. I am just a user and trying to send message after mms but sms remains in sending state until mms does not sent.
So, i just want to know is it related to android M ?

Comment: You're asking on the wrong site, then. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.